# Why is the worldvolume theory a $U(1)$ gauge theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, branes

So in string theory a Dp-brane can be described by a $(p+1)$ dimensional QFT living in its worldvolume.  For a string, this is similar to the description of the string as a twodimensional QFT living on its worldsheet. This is called worldvolume theory. My question is, why is this theory a $U(1)$ gauge theory, and what is exactly meant by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a massless field that transforms as a Lorentz vector on the brane. The associated field is a Maxwell gauge field living on
the brane. Therefore the world volume theory is a $U(1)$ theory.

(Ps. This is totally QFT related, so pretty strange that a mod removed the tag)